# How to detect where default_socket_timeout happens?

Tags: php, apache

I have a 3rd party large code, and it has a timeout flaw. I don't know where in the code

How to detect where does `default_socket_timeout` happen in code?

Comment: Yes, that depends on the code. :/ I suggest you contact the project maintaining the code and call for support there.

Comment: The project has been abandoned, and clearly tries to reach out for a page that doesn't exists and hangs on.

Comment: uhh, that's bad. Have you tried with PHP error handling and watching for warnings? Also it's probably possible to add an event callback in the default stream context if that library uses it.